# CommandParameter usage in KeyInput Bindings Vs. Button bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, commandparameter

The following two elements are firing in my implementation of ICommand differently and causing problems. When the implementation enters CanExecuteChanged(object parameter) for the TextBox, the value of parameter is null. When it enters the same method for the Button, the value of parameter is equal to the CommandParameter.

Ideally I'd like in both cases that the CommandParameter value is not sent to the CanExecuteChanged, only to Execute.

Implementation of ICommand

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add
            {
                canExecuteChanged += value;
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            }
            remove
            {
                canExecuteChanged -= value;
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
            }
        }


        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            if (parameter is bool)
            {
                this.canExecute = (bool)parameter;
            }

            return this.canExecute;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            this.executeAction((T)parameter);
        }              


        internal void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
        {           
            this.OnCanExecuteChanged();
        }


        private void OnCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            if (this.canExecuteChanged != null)
            {
                this.canExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
```

TextBox

```
<TextBox Width="80" Margin="2,2,2,2" Text="{Binding LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MaxLength="25">
                <TextBox.InputBindings>
                    <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding SearchCommand}">
                        <KeyBinding.CommandParameter>
                            <s:Boolean>True</s:Boolean>
                        </KeyBinding.CommandParameter>
                    </KeyBinding>
                </TextBox.InputBindings>
            </TextBox>
```

Button

```
<Button Margin="2,2,2,2" Padding="10,0,10,0" Content="Search">
                <Button.InputBindings>
                    <MouseBinding Command="{Binding SearchCommand }" MouseAction="LeftClick">
                        <MouseBinding.CommandParameter>
                            <s:Boolean>True</s:Boolean>
                        </MouseBinding.CommandParameter>
                    </MouseBinding>
                </Button.InputBindings>
            </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, try the implementation `ICommand` of `@JoshSmith`, for me both options worked well:

**`RelayCommand`**

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
        }

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }

        remove
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

**`SearchCommand`**

```
private RelayCommand _searchCommand = null;

public ICommand SearchCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_searchCommand == null)
        {
            _searchCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.Search(param), param => true);
        }

        return _searchCommand;
    }
}

private void Search(object param)
{
    bool parameter = (bool)param;

    if (parameter) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Pressed the Enter Key");
    }
}
```

Comment: First thing Monday morning

Comment: Not quite. The command parameter for button still appears to be used in both execute and can execute

Comment: @Kevin: So you `do not need` to parameter passed, but then why did you convey? Something I do not quite understand.

Comment: I need a CommandParameter for the execute statement. My trouble is that I need to set CanExecute to false while the command is running so it cannot be triggered until the execution is complete. In the case of  the TextBoxes this works - because when the CanExecute fires from the TextBox's input binding it does not receive the CommandParameter. However when the CanExecute fires from the Button, it does.

Comment: @Kevin:  Maybe in this case it is easier to set `IsEnabled` to False for Control until the task is executed. In fact it will be the same and easy, I guess.